# How to calculate prime factorization of `0.5`?

Tags: javascript, prime-factoring

How to calculate prime factorization of `0.5` ?

I am trying to understand this line.

**JavaScript cannot precisely represent a decimal fraction whose denominator’s prime factorization contains a number other than 2. For example, 0.5 (12) can be represented, while 0.6 (35) cannot**

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how JavaScript represents decimals using the IEEE floating point system. Basically, floating point number an integer is raised to a power of 2. Only numbers that can be written as

```
± n * 2^k
```

where n and k are integers(with some limits) can be represented exactly.

0.5 (1/2) only has `2` as a prime factor and is represented as 1 * 2^(-1). 0.6 (3/5) cannot be represented exactly because it has 3 and 5 as prime factors.

http://blog.chewxy.com/2014/02/24/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-point-numbers/#IEEE_754